How to combine a 12V DC Motor in a Light Fixture with Dimmer & 12V DC to 110V AC Inverter?
I have a question regarding a light fixture I'm building that also has a motor in it. It has geometric shapes that spin slowly around the light (almost like a mobile) and this is what I'm using the motor for. The light fixture will be attached to the ceiling like any normal light fixture or chandelier and I want to use a light switch on the wall to be able to turn it on and off. The light bulbs will be powered by 110V AC. The 12V Synchronous DC motor will be powered by 12V DC. I am using an Inverter which is 12 Volt DC To 110 Volt AC which will be able to accommodate turning both the motor and bulbs on with a flick of the light switch on the wall.
The question I have is in regards to a dimmer switch. I want to use a dimmer switch to be able to make the lights brighter or dimmer. However, because the motor is also being controlled by the dimmer switch I want to know if this will be a problem and what will happen. Will it slow down the rotation? Will It damage the motor? If it will pose a problem are there any simple solutions or work arounds? I haven't purchased the dimmer switch yet. Is there a certain type that will work with this or a certain type that won't?
Just to clarify why I'm going about it this way. Initially I was just going to use an AC 110 V motor so it would all be on AC. The problem was getting UL approval because of the motor. Because I'm using a 12 V DC motor instead it is kind of a loophole for me so I can get UL approval without all the headaches. Using a 12V DC motor will not be a safety concern in terms of UL certification.
The motor I'm using is a 12V Synchronous DC geared 1 RPM motor. It's just a simple one you can buy on Amazon and I'll post the link to it: https://www.amazon.ca/gp/product/B07YFJR62T/ref=pp...
Also, on a side note I'm not sure what inverter I should use for this project. The choice is between a constant current inverter/driver vs constant voltage inverter/driver. I'm not sure which one to use here.

"Loophole" and "UL approval" usually don't belong in the same sentence, let alone the same product. "Synchronous DC motor" is a bit of an oxymoron to me since "synchronous" means that the rotation is synchronized to the applied AC waveform, which in your case there is none. This sounds like a case of a shady manufacturer putting random words on a label, which isn't something that screams "quality" to me (neither does Amazon). An inverter takes in DC and produces AC at the output; it sounds like you need a AC to DC converter, unless you are actually trying to wire 12 VDC to the device.

why does a DC motor say 50/60 Hz 0.8/1RPM ?

you described a system where the light switch controls 12 Vdc ... is that what you actually have?

Let me clarify what I mean by loophole. Because I'm using the 12V DC motor I won't have the same problems I would have getting UL certification (it gets tricky getting UL certified with an AC motor). From a UL certification safety standpoint, the motor won't be an electrical hazard if it's 12V DC but it will if it's on 110V AC. In terms of UL certification they basically don't care if the motor is running on 12V as it is actually safer this way and will not be a fire or safety hazard.  It's not shady it is actually safer to do it this way.  Yes, converter is the correct word, not inverter.

Secondly, I'm only in the test phased of making this.  I had a heck of a time even finding a small DC motor that only rotates at 1 rpm.  They are very difficult to find.  For testing, I want to make sure this even works without having to build my own motor or commisioning someone to build it for me.  Once I do figure out the prototype and see what works I will making my own North American made motor.

The switch will control both the 12V dc motor and the 110v light bulbs in which these will use a converter.

I don't understand your question about why a DC motor says 50/60 Hz 0.8/1RPM.  This is a super slow motor.  It rotates very slowly, similar to a disco ball.  It will rotate at 0.8-1.0 RPM per minute which is extremely slow for a motor but what I want.  This is not supposed to be a powerful or fast motor. The objects move at extremely slow speed.

The problem is that the label says both DC which means 0 Hz and 50/60 Hz, which is not 0. Try searching for DC gearmotors which can give you arbitrarily low RPMs. Searching for exactly 1 RPM is going to clog up your searches since people are using those for clocks and they will almost always be synchronized to grid power, which implies AC. If for some reason, you do need 1 RPM, then you'll need an encoder, feedback loop, etc. Also, 1 RPM could be too low, disco balls are like 20 RPM.

I added a picture to show what it is I'm trying to do here.
